# class that simulates bi-dimensional table in JAVA

Tags: java, sorting, dynamic-arrays

```
public class table 
{
private int raw=0;
private int column=0;
private List<ArrayList<Integer>> TABLE ;
private static int COUNT_ELEMENTS_IN_RAW=0;
private static int COUNT_ELEMENTS_TOTAL=0;
private List<Integer> singleRaw ;
public table()
{
    TABLE = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    singleRaw = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
public void addELEMENT(Integer value)
{   
    if(!TABLE.equals(null))
    {

        singleRaw.addAll(TABLE.get(raw));
        singleRaw.add(value);
        COUNT_ELEMENTS_IN_RAW++;
        if(COUNT_ELEMENTS_IN_RAW%14==0)
        {
            raw++;
            COUNT_ELEMENTS_IN_RAW=0;
            COUNT_ELEMENTS_TOTAL++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

here i´m trying to simulate 2-dimensional table(xy),function addELEMENT performs insertion into the "table".
anybody can explain me why gives me that error ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at pt.iul.poo.games.table.addELEMENT(table.java:27)
```

Comment: It looks like you are squeezing the juice out of dried or empty Arraylist.

Comment: i changed to TABLE!=null,but gives me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
singleRaw.addAll(TABLE.get(raw));
                 ^^^^^^
```

The *Exception* you're getting is very informative:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

It's telling you that the `List` is of size 0, and you're trying to `TABLE.get(raw));` where `raw` is 0, but if `TABLE` is of size 0, you **can't** get the element at 0. You do have an `List` but it's **empty**, you didn't insert anything to it.

You should also change `if(!TABLE.equals(null))` to `if(TABLE != null)`, because if `TABLE` is `null`, this will throw a *NPE* since it'll be evaluated to `!null.equals(null)`

Also, try to follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) and change `TABLE` to table and your class to `Table`.

Comment: Insert elements to `TABLE` before you try to get elements from it.

Comment: i have one problem,can you write me some code to manipulate this table please?

Comment: Make an `ArrayList<Integer>`, then add it to the `TABLE` List. Try to do that, if you couldn't let me know.

Comment: yes,already done
but I don´t understand how to add to this TABLE next line ?
because i´ll need to make one function that will return some element at specific point.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the collection type that [`Guava`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) includes?  [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html), which supports this use case for any "row" type and "column" type.

```
Table<Integer, Integer, String> table = HashBasedTable.create();
table.put(0, 0, "A"); // row 0, column 0
table.put(0, 1, "B"); // row 0, column 1

// One element
final String value = table.get(0, 1); // "B"

// Column 0
final Collection<String> strs = table.column(0).values();

// Row 1
final Collection<String> strs = table.row(1).values();
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at line:

```
singleRaw.addAll(TABLE.get(raw));
```

There is the exception because of

```
TABLE.get(raw)
```

TABLE is empty so cannot get index 0